# How to pipe text for a Mutt email body, then edit the email interactively?

Tags: bash, mutt, stdin

I've been trying to figure out how to start Mutt in such a way that it's just like starting up an interactive Mutt and creating a new email, then copying the output of `git request-pull` into the body (to be able to edit it manually). `git request-pull HEAD https://... | mutt -i- invalid@example.org`  doesn't work - It just exits with exit code 0 and no message at all, and I'm not even sure if anything was sent, because there's no copy of the email in the standard sent folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you want to edit the mail before it is sent? In that case piping is not going to work because `mutt` receives an `EOF` when the pipe closes. Either use an actual file or use process substitution, a `ksh93` feature also available in `bash` and `zsh`, e.g.:

```
mutt -i<(git request-pull HEAD https://...) -s SUBJECT invalid@example.org
```